# How can i get guild name using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has been kicked by {ctx.author.name}\nReason: {reason}")
    await ctx.send(member, f"You have been kicked from {member.guild.name} reason: {reason}"
```

This is the return

```
from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Messageable.send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in this line: `await ctx.send(member, f"You have been kicked from {member.guild.name} reason: {reason}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that ctx.send() takes 1 or 2 positional arguments, and you've provided 3. In python, methods implicitly pass self, so this line:

```
await ctx.send(member, f"You have been kicked from {member.guild.name} reason: {reason}"
```

Actually is passing three arguments, because there's an implicit self at the start. Since ctx.send() needs either 0 or 1 parameters of your own, what you probably actually want is this:

```
await ctx.send(f"{member}, you have been kicked from {member.guild.name} reason: {reason}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):

    # Send the message to the member being kicked
    # `ctx.guild.name` - Guild Name
    # Sending the message should be done before kicking the member
    # I have had experience where the bot is unable to send the message to `member`
    #    Because both the bot and the member are not in a server
    await member.send(f"You have been kicked from {ctx.guild.name} reason: {reason}")

    # Kicking the member
    await member.kick(reason=reason)

    # Sending the message to the channel where the command has been used
    await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has been kicked by {ctx.author.name}\nReason: {reason}")
```